# Is there such a thing as the inverse of a section of a function? How would that be defined?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, product-space

I have the function $f:A\times B \to C$ and I want to write its inverse $f^{-1}$ in terms of the inverse of the sections of the function $f$.

The sections are 
$$a\to f(a,b) \quad (\forall b\in B,a\in A) \equiv f^b(a)$$ 
and 
$$b\to f(a,b) \quad (\forall a\in A,b\in B) \equiv f_a(b)$$

Do the inverse functions $(f^b)^{-1}$ and $(f_a)^{-1}$ exist?
Because for some fixed $a$, there is not necessarily a $B_0\in B$ such that $f_a(B_0) = O$. So at best $f_a(B_0)\subset O$. If they do exist how are they defined? If not, what is the closest concept?

Comment: For an inverse to exist, you need the function to be injective.  If $f$ is injective, there is no reason to think the sections are.  Similarly for surjective.

Comment: All this is very unclear. What exactly are your "sections", and what is the intended meaning of $f^{-1}$? Note that for an arbitrary $f:\>X\to Y$ we only have the preimage map $f^{-1}:\>{\cal P}(Y)\to{\cal P}(X)$.

Comment: @GEdgar That's also what I was thinking. I guess you just have to work with sets in this situation

Comment: @ChristianBlatter $f^{-1}$ is the preimage. A section is a concept when you have a function on a product space. In that case you can have the section of a function, by fixing one dimension using a constant, so as to end up with a function in one dimension. I was asking whether there is such a concept as the preimage of a section of a function.